# kubuntu: pppoeconf broke ethernet interface, KDE still doesn't see it after fixing

Tags: networking, kde, pppoe

I cannot create create a DSL connection in KDE, the OK button is inactive, so i installed `pppoeconf` to use DSL connection at the new place. Now I'm back home and I tried to use an ordinary Ethernet connection. However, KDE doesn't see anything:

[image: screenshot]

After checking `/etc/network/interfaces` I found that my Ethernet is set to manual

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set enp37s0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto enp37s0
iface enp37s0 inet manual
```

So I commented out everything related to `dsl-provider` and wrote

```
auto enp37s0
iface enp37s0 inet dhcp
```

Now I'm able to see the `enp37s0` interface in KDE Network Interfaces (before only `lo` was present), and my Internet works. But KDE itself still refuses to see any wired connections (see screenshot).

Ubuntu 16.04 amd64

Comment: If KDE is anything like regular Ubuntu, then its network-manager ignores any interfaces that are configured via the older networking service - try commenting out everything in /etc/network/interfaces **except** the `lo` portion.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you very much! It worked !!